# Using remap function opencv 2.3.1

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV's `remap` function as shown below:

```
Mat lg,lr;
Mat *mxl = (Mat *) cvLoad("mx1.xml");
Mat *myl = (Mat *) cvLoad("my1.xml");
remap(lg, lr, mxl, myl);
```

`mx1` and `my1` are loaded as `cv::Mat`, but `remap` needs `cv::_InputArray`, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::_InputArray` is a proxy type used by OpenCV to accept multiple data types (like `cv::Mat` or `std::vector`) as inputs. You don't need to create one directly.

Part of your problem is that you're attempting to mix the C and C++ APIs. This is not recommended. Another factor is that `cv::Mat*` cannot be converted to `InputArray`. You can use `cv::FileStorage` to read your files into `cv::Mat` objects:

```
cv::Mat lg, lr;
cv::FileStorage fs1("mx1.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
cv::FileStorage fs2("mx2.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);

cv::Mat mxl;
cv::FileNode fn = fs1.getFirstTopLevelNode();
fn >> mxl;

cv::Mat myl;
fn = fs2.getTopLevelNode();
fn >> myl;

cv::remap(lg, lr, mxl, myl, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```

Comment: Using OpenCV 2.4.8 - getTopLevelNode seems to have been renamed to getFirstTopLevelNode.